# Update TableAdapter with DataSet - Update requires a valid DeleteCommand error

Tags: c#, winforms

In the code below what does "Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows." mean?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{
    fuelStopsDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[item.Index].Delete();
}

this.fuelStopsTableAdapter.Update(this.fuelStopsDataSet1.FuelStops);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you are using a `DataAdapter` to update a table which contains deleted `DataRows` (their [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) is `Deleted`). Then the `DataAdapter` uses the specified  [`DeleteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand.aspx)   to delete this row in the database. But you haven't provided it.

So you need to provide it.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand.aspx) example:

```
public static SqlDataAdapter CreateCustomerAdapter(
    SqlConnection connection)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    // Create the SelectCommand.
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers " +
        "WHERE Country = @Country AND City = @City", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
    command.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    // Create the InsertCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " +
        "VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName)", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the InsertCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName");

    adapter.InsertCommand = command;

    // Create the UpdateCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, CompanyName = @CompanyName " +
        "WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName");
    SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
        "@oldCustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

    // Create the DeleteCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the DeleteCommand.
    parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
        "@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    adapter.DeleteCommand = command;

    return adapter;
}
```

The last command is the `DeleteCommand`.

Answer (score 5):

You can have the DeleteCommand be created automatically in some situations (inferred from the SelectCommand).

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("...SELECT Statement...", connection);
SqlCommandBuilder cmd_b = new SqlCommandBuilder(da); // this already creates 
// the Update- and DeleteCommands for the DA
```

Here is an article about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/tf579hcz.aspx