# Cannot delete a datagrid row and save the remaining rows back in database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to remove one row from a datagridview when user selects a row and then clicks the "Delete" button. I am using the following code:

```
        private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvSearchResults.ReadOnly = false;
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
                dgvSearchResults.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvSearchResults.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                ole_da.Update(dTable);
            }
        }
```

And I am getting the following error when debugging:

> {"Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows."}

I am pretty new to C# and have no idea how to create a DeleteCommand or use CommandBuilder (as suggested in some SO posts) to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478202/update-tableadapter-with-dataset-update-requires-a-valid-deletecommand-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click event do that:

```
ole_da.SelectCommand = yourSelectCommand;             
OleDbCommandBuilder oleDbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(ole_da);
ole_da.Update(dTable);
```

Comment: I have no select command in my above code. Where should I add it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Orkun-Bekar, the following finally solved the problem:

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvSearchResults.ReadOnly = false;
            if (MessageBox.Show("Delete?", "confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
                dgvSearchResults.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvSearchResults.SelectedRows[0].Index);

                ole_da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Projects");
                ole_da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;
                oleCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(ole_da);
                ole_da.Update(dTable);

            }
        }
```

Where, ole_da is given a select command that selects all items from the table in question. It's then given a connection i.e. *conn*. Making use of OleDbCommandBuilder class then will automate the deletion of the selected row, without needing for an explicit DeleteCommand to be specified.